# Вывод категорий из кастомной таксономии

Tags: wordpress

У меня есть свой post_type "services", у него своя таксономия "services-category" для рубрик. Ну и соответственно записи в этом post_type распределены по рубрикам, только в каждой рубрике есть запись, которая соответствует рубрике. Например есть рубрика "kt", у нее есть описание, картинка, название, в этой рубрике лежит запись "kt", а также и другие записи.

И мне нужно на странице /services вывести список всех рубрик из "services-category" вместо с их описание и тд, затем при переходе из этого списка в конкретную рубрику, например в "kt" (/services/kt), нужно вывести контент этой записи, а также список всех записей относящихся к этой рубрике

Пробовал в archive-services.php выводить через get_categories рубрики, все выводилось, но после перехода на конкретную рубрику подключался single.php, а на некоторые page.php

Как правильно реализовать данную затею?

```
<?
$categories = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy'      => array( 'services-category' ), // название таксономии с WP 4.5
    'orderby'       => 'name',
    'order'         => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty'    => false,
) );

if( $categories ):
    foreach( $categories as $cat ):
        $image_id = get_term_meta( $cat->term_id, '_thumbnail_id', 1 );
        $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_url( $image_id, 'full' );
        ?>
        <div class="col2">
            <div class="service">
                <div class="preview">
                    <img src="<?= $image_url ?>">
                </div>
                <div class="description box">
                    <h2><a href="<?= get_term_link($cat) ?>"><?= $cat->name?></a></h2>
                    <p><?= $cat->description?></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?endforeach;
endif;
?>
```

Comment: Ни одного вопроса. Все предложения начинаются на "У меня есть", "Мне нужно"...

Comment: Соответственно вопрос, как это сделать)

Comment: Как вы выводите ссылки на категории? Добавьте код в вопрос

Comment: @DarthKYL, сделал. Все шаблоны типа "taxonomy-services-category-archive" или "taxonomy-services-category" не работают

Comment: вы обновляли пермалинки после того как добавили кастомную таксономию? потому что сейчас из описания вашего вопроса следует что у таксономии и у записи одинаковые ссылки

Comment: @DarthKYL, обновлял. Но я хочу чтобы на странице таксономии выводился контект записи и также список записей этой таксономии

Comment: контент какой именно записи? на странице таксономии оторажается ее описание и список записей принадлежащих этой таксономии

Comment: @DarthKYL, ну вот например у меня есть категория "kt", в ней должен отображаться произвольный контент и список записей, относящихся к этой категории. Я думал сделать так - создать таксономию "kt" и запись "kt", ну и выводить контент записи kt и список записей соот таксономии

Answer (score 1, accepted):

я думаю вам нужно чтото вроде этого, если вы хотите иметь страницу у которой ярлык такой же как и у таксономии.

в шаблоне таксономии вы можете получить ее ярлык и по ярлыку выбрать соответствующую запись

```
$taxonomy_slug = get_query_var( 'taxonomy' );
$page = get_page_by_path( $taxonomy_slug, OBJECT, 'services' );
if ( is_a( $page, 'WP_Post' ) ) {
    // ваш код
}
```

Comment: Возможно, но проблема в том, что у меня шаблоны таксономии не подключаются(, у меня две категории открывают single, а следующие page

Comment: 1. вам нужно использовать taxonomy-services-category.php для ваших таксономий
2. если таксономии ведут на другие ссылки значит у вас не обновленны пермалинки, либо вы используете функционал который их изменяет. по умолчанию для категории kt должна быть такая линка /services-category/kt

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо, посмотрю